# Laptop overheating causing frame drops in Fortnite

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have an HP laptop with an Intel core i7-7500u @2.7ghz-2.9ghz, 8gb ram, Intel hd graphics 620 and a 60hz screen.

I have been experiencing overheating and frame drops while playing Fortnite on this laptop. I play at a resolution of 1024x768 and generally get about 50-60 fps on low settings. However after a decent time of playing or when I come back from a break, Fortnite will then have frame drops to about 6-13.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The simple fix is you stop playing until the laptop cools down.

If you want to keep playing, you can try a laptop cooling pad.  However, the nature of a laptop is that they do not handle extended intense use very well.

I own a gaming laptop and the thing has heatsink and vents all around the base.  Even with this setup, the laptop can get hot enough that I can feel it through the keyboard.

Of course, this means that the heat is actually coming out of the machine and lets it run at a sustained level, so I'm glad I can feel the heat.

Answer (score 0):

Although Nelson recommends cooling pads but then goes against them I must disagree. I used to own the world's hottest laptop that would constantly straight shut down when it gets too hot. On the left of the mouse pad it was black because of all the heat. IF you find a cooling pad, that has fan placement exactly the same as where your laptop's vents are, you'll have a much better experience. I managed to find a fanned pad once that was exactly like that and it'd keep my laptop quite cold.

The next thing you REALLY need to do is either pay for someone or find a video on youtube - how to clean your laptop. It really needs to be done quite frequently. Some people recommend every 6-12 months. There will be a lot of dust and gunk blocking all the air ways if the laptop has never been cleaned before. I'd take this opportunity to also change the CPU and GPU's  thermal paste (they are very inexpensive).

Cleaning it will make all the difference in the world.

P.P. (As it's an HP and those are horrible to open, I do recommend you take it to a hardware shop, they don't usually charge alot, I had to take my old HP literally apart to clean the dust properly, ever part had to be unscrewed ...)

Answer (score 0):

As @Nelson said, giving your laptop breaks to cool down is a good idea. Also try lowering the resolution in the Fortnite settings. I also suggest playing on stretched. Take a look at this [article](https://www.prosettings.com/fortnite-custom-stretched-resolution/)